# Restrict RDP Access by IP in Server 2003 (SP1)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

We have a product in our environment that is a virtual machine, running Windows Server 2003, standard edition (SP 1). Due to the vulnerabilites, our security group is requesting that I limit RDP access by specific IP.

I'm having trouble finding and enabling this capability, is there actually a way to restrict RDP access only by IP?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for Windows 2003's IP Security Policy Management feature. [CodeHill](https://codehill.com/2010/02/how-to-block-ip-addresses-in-windows-server-2003/) has a good tutorial. So does [Managed.com](https://support.managed.com/kb/a482/block-an-ip-or-ip-range-using-windows-ip-security-policy.aspx).

Highlights:

- Start mmc.exe and add the IP Security Policy Management snap-in.
- Right-click on `IP Security Policies on Local Computer`. Select `Create IP Security Policy...`.
- Follow the wizard.

There is also a command-line version -- [IPSecCmd.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/813878/how-to-block-specific-network-protocols-and-ports-by-using-ipsec).

Another good tutorial: http://winhosts.blogspot.com/2012/09/set-up-ip-security-policy-rule-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Server 2003 SP1 already has the Windows Firewall built in.

1. Run `firewall.cpl` or go _Control Panel → Windows Firewall`
2. In the exception list, select "Remote Desktop" and click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Change Scope', then enter a comma-separated list custom IP addresses, or address/netmask pairs, or CIDR address/plen pairs.